# Unable to read entire header; 353 bytes read; expected 512 bytes

Tags: android, excel, ioexception

In my Android app, I import input data from .xls and .xlsx format Excel sheets. It worked fine for sample data used. But for final check, when tested with actual input data, it throws below error.

```
Error log: :java.io.IOException: Unable to read entire header; 353 bytes read; expected 512 bytes :Exception
```

I have answers in SO, but they lack the explanation of how to fix the scenario in Android environment.

**EDIT :**

The input [.xls and .xlsx file ] is generated by Oracle Form. This has to be imported in Android. If I open the input file in MS Excel and save it. It gets imported without any issue. But I can't do this every time [ open and save using MS Excel ].

Appreciate help.

**Reason found:** ORACLE only exports [.CSV] and saves as [.xls] which is not a valid excel sheet and when it is read using Java code below, throws error [ exclusively for ORACLE exported [.xls] and not for Excel created [.xls]

```
try {
       if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
       {                        
            FileInputStream inStream;

            inStream = new FileInputStream(FilePath);
            Sheet sheet1 = null;

            if (GetFileExtension(FilePath).equals(".xls")) {

                // Workbook wb= new HSSFWorkbook(inStream);
                // sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);

                NPOIFSFileSystem fs = new NPOIFSFileSystem(inStream);
                Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs.getRoot(), true);

                sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);

            }
            else if (GetFileExtension(FilePath).equals(".xlsx")) {
            
                    Workbook wb= new XSSFWorkbook(inStream);
                    sheet1 =  wb.getSheetAt(0);

        }
                 
.............
.............
.............

}
catch(Exception e){
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
```

After a week time of research, I found that only there are two solutions

1. ORA_EXCEL Package by [2atOnce](https://www.oraexcel.com/) - Paid
2. ASLX Package by [Anton Scheffer](https://technology.amis.nl/2011/02/19/create-an-excel-file-with-plsql/) - Free

**Apache POI code block that throws error**

```
public HeaderBlock(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
        // Grab the first 512 bytes
       // (For 4096 sized blocks, the remaining 3584 bytes are zero)
        // Then, process the contents
        this(readFirst512(stream));
        
        // Fetch the rest of the block if needed
        if(bigBlockSize.getBigBlockSize() != 512) {
           int rest = bigBlockSize.getBigBlockSize() - 512;
           byte[] tmp = new byte[rest];
           IOUtils.readFully(stream, tmp);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You do this all without code?

Comment: Is there a way to override HeaderBlock of Apache POI? and skip grabbing the first 512 bytes ?